# Code stops executing for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, foreach, datatable

This is C# Winforms.

I have a list of strings in this code:

```
List<string> WaveAndPickFields = new List<string>(new string[] { "ID", "TransactionID", "OrderNumber", "WarehouseID", "StoreOrderNumber", "OrderType", "CustomerID", "CustomerPONumber", "DepartmentCode", "LoadNumber", "ReverseLoadSequence", "BOLNumber", "MasterBOLNumber", "ProNumber", "Carrier", "CarrierSCAC", "FreightTerms", "RushOrderFlag", "OrderEntryDate", "ExpectedCarrierArrivalDate", "DatePromised", "OrderWeight", "OrderCubicVolume", "OrderCartonCounts", "ShippingShort", "PrepaidFreight", "CODAmount", "InsuranceAmount", "PIPAmount", "TotalFreightCost", "ShipToCustomerCode", "ShipToName", "ShipToAddress1", "ShipToAddress2", "ShipToAddress3", "ShipToCity", "ShipToState", "ShipToZipCode", "ShipToCountryCode", "ShipToCountryName", "BillToCustomerCode", "BillToName", "BillToAddress1", "BillToAddress2", "BillToAddress3", "BillToCity", "BillToState", "BillToZipCode", "BillToCountryCode", "BillToCountryName", "DeliveryAddressName", "DeliveryAddress1", "DeliveryAddress2", "DeliveryAddress3", "DeliveryCity", "DeliveryState", "DeliveryZipCode", "DeliveryCountryCode", "DeliveryCountryName", "DeliveryPhone", "BillFreightCustomerCode", "BillFreightAddressName", "BillFreightAddress1", "BillFreightAddress2", "BillFreightAddress3", "BillFreightCity", "BillFreightState", "BillFreightZipCode", "BillFreightCountryCode", "BillFreightCountryName", "CartonLabel", "ShipVerificationFlag", "PartialOrderFlag", "EarliestShipDate", "LatestShipDate", "EarliestDeliveryDate", "LatestDeliveryDate", "PromoCode", "Route", "Stop", "ToteFlag", "Status" });
```

All I want to do is loop through this code and add a bunch of fields to a datatable.  I am doing it in this code:

```
foreach (string field in WaveAndPickFields)
{
    dtWaveAndPicks.Columns.Add(field);
}
```

I have also tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < WaveAndPickFields.Count; i++)
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn(WaveAndPickFields[i]);
    dtWaveAndPicks.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

For whatever reason these lines appear to execute but the entire function stops and nothing else executes without an exception error.

```
dtWaveAndPicks.Columns.Add(field);
```

and:

```
dtWaveAndPicks.Columns.Add(column);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?  The alternative that does work for me is having a line that will add a column.  The problem is, I didn't want to have 80+ lines to add the fields when I could have had a loop like this.

Comment: "For whatever reason these lines appear to execute but the entire function stops and nothing else executes without an exception error."  What lines?  The question is a bit ambiguous, could you try to sharpen things up a bit?

Comment: How is `dtWaveAndPicks` instantiated and what happens to it before loop?

Comment: if your list represents a single row,dtWaveAndPicks.Rows.Add(WaveAndPickFields.ToArray());

Comment: @Ecnalyr the last two highlighted lines. Basically the ones where he calls the `Add` method of the DataColumnCollection.

Comment: Are your loops running on a thread that is not the Main GUI thread? Only the GUI thread can make calls to GUI elements.

Comment: This is as sharp as I can make it.  Thoses lines are touched in the debug, and after I hit either F10 or F11, debugging stops.  I have even placed a MessageBox directly after those lines and also just after the loop and neither show.

Comment: @lgor, the datatable is instantiated like this...

DataTable dtWaveAndPicks = new DataTable();

nothing happens to the datatable before I do this.

Comment: @ScottMiller, My loop is in the form load event.

Comment: @terrybozzio my list represents the column names.  I am trying to add columns to the data table.

Comment: @hondaman2003 - The code that you showed works. Search around it. Do you have any `try/catch` blocks that hide any exceptions?

Comment: @Igor, I tried it again and it worked as well.  I truly do not know what is going on.  I commented out the code that didn't work and just un-commented it back out to try it again and it worked.  I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time but thank you for everyone that responded.

Comment: As an added comment, I do not have any try/catch blocks because this is a new form and I want to see exceptions if they happen.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest using windbg to determine what's going on here - if you haven't used it before it can be a bit daunting but there's quite good tutorials (particularly from Tess [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/))

Once you've got windbg installed get a process dump via task manager when the hang occurs
Open the dump file in windbg

Then run `.symfix c:\sos` to fix the symbol path

Next load sos `.loadby sos mscorwks`

Finally to check for an exception on any thread run `.foreach (ex {!dumpheap -type Exception -short}){.echo "********************************";!pe –nested ${ex} }`

Give this a try & see how you get on

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I am going to look into this.  For now however, I must have been doing something wrong that I cannot identify but I am good now.

Comment: So what are the Visual studio tools for? They aren't enough, are they?

Comment: In most development cases then yes, the VS tools are enough, however there are cases when more advanced debug utilities are required. The most common (in my experience) is when the application is deployed to production, starts crashing or hanging and the logs are insufficent to identify the root cause. Other cases include multithreaded applications where the use of break points can hide issues, finally there are cases where managed and unmanaged code are used in conjunction